# Thread.CurrentPrincipal in .NET console application

Tags: .net, security, windows-7, .net-4.0, principal

Here is a trivial console application that i run in command prompt:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
namespace Test
{
    internal class Runner
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.GetType().Name);
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

The output is 'GenericPrincipal' and empty string as identity name. Why the run-time constructs `GenericPrincipal` instead of `WindowsPrincipal`? How do i force it to construct `WindowsPrincipal` from the security token of the starting process (cmd.exe in my case)?

Comment: What do you get when you query `WindowsIdentity current = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();` ??

Comment: It returns my current windows identity as i expect. So is it my responsibility to construct and attach the principal? Or there is a way to specify it in the configuration file just like security setting in ASP.NET or WCF application?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You have to tell your app what PrincipalPolicy to use.  You would add

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
```

making your code look like:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Security.Principal;

namespace Test
{
    internal class Runner
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetPrincipalPolicy(PrincipalPolicy.WindowsPrincipal);
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.GetType().Name);
            Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.setprincipalpolicy.aspx